# Do I need two connection strings in web.config?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am having problems in my code. I have this class in the file KekantoContext.cs

```
  public class KekantoContext : DbContext
{

    public DbSet<Lugar> Lugares { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Categoria> Categorias { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserMessage> UserMessages { get; set; }

  }
```

And I have another class in the AccountModel.cs file:

```
 public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}
```

I want to know if it's necessary to have 2 connection strings in my web.config file.

I have this:

```
    <connectionStrings>
  <add name="KekantoContext"
 connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Kekanto.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

   <add name="UsersContext"
 connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Kekanto.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

</connectionStrings>
```

The code didn't work with these 2 connectionStrings, but I want to know if a possible solution needs 2 connection string

Answer (score 0):

```
     public class UsersContext : DbContext
     {
         public UsersContext()
           : base("UsersContext")
         {
         }

          public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
     }
```

Comment: Now I am habing problems in runTime...
It says that:"The model backing the 'UsersContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database " Even if I make the migration, it still doesnt work

Comment: Check that the UserProfile object within the code matches the fields in the database to which the connection string is pointing to.  These need to match perfectly otherwise it can't map between the database and your local object.

Answer (score 0):

I think it ok to have tor parameter the name of uctwo connection string you just have to pass in to the he string the name of the string you want to use.

```
public UsersContext()
        : base("UsersContext")
    {

    }
```

or you can do it at runtime

```
   public UsersContext(string connect)
            : base(connect)
        {

        }

UserContext =  new UserContext("UsersContext");
```